# Laravel excel keep validating data after rows ended

Tags: laravel, validation, import-from-excel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

[validating another 989 rows][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ErrL.png

i created import function with laravel-excel and i make a column as required. The file contains 10 rows,  but after doing check in the failures it always return another 989 rows below the datas & heading.. any suggestion ?

my controller

```
      public function import(Request $request)
    {
        $import = new StudentsImport;

        $import->import($request->file('file'));

        foreach ($import->failures() as $failure) {
            foreach ($failure->errors() as $key => $value) {
                $test[] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $test;

    }
```

my import

```
    class StudentsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, SkipsOnError, WithValidation, SkipsOnFailure
{
    use SkipsErrors;
    use Importable;
    use SkipsFailures;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'name' => $row['nama_siswa'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
            'username' => $row['nisn'],
            'password' => $row['password'],
            'dob' =>  $row['dob'],
            'nisn' => $row['nisn']
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'nisn'      => 'required|numeric'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same error, the problem is not your code, the problem is Excel, I deleted all the rows after the data in Excel and then it worked correctly, good luck. also, I'm using https://laravel-excel.com/

Comment: Hello friend, did you manage to solve it? I have the same error.

Comment: @edocollado Hi bro, I don't understand how to delete rows after the data. For example, I have an excel file with several records and I import it and the records are created in the DB but it continues to show a validation error as if it were a loop.

Answer (score 0):

@juanzu, If your Excel file has 10 records and you encounter an error, try deleting all the rows after the data. To do this, follow these steps:

- Click on the cell in row 11 (the row immediately after your data).
- Press Ctrl + Shift + Down Arrow to select all the rows below.
- Press Ctrl + Shift + Right Arrow to select all the columns to the right.
- Right-click the selected area, and choose the "Delete" option from the context menu that appears.
  After doing this, the issue should be resolved.

However, you mentioned that after importing the data and creating records in the database, you still see a validation error as if there's a loop. Please clarify your question so I can better understand the issue and provide further guidance.